# Group by tables with different fields based on the year on the date on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have one table with 4 data with the same id, id each have a value with type a different date.

```
  id   |   name  |    date     |   status  |
------ | ------- | ----------- | --------- |
  1    |  steve  |  2015-09-12 | scheduled |
  2    |  steve  |  2015-09-09 |   actual  |
  3    |  steve  |  2016-01-10 | scheduled |
  4    |  steve  |  2016-01-21 |   actual  |
```

I want to display the data in tabular form based on the year, .

```
  id   |  name  |           2014           |           2016            | 
       |        |  scheduled  |   actual   |  scheduled   |   actual   |
------ | ------ | ----------- | ---------- | ------------ | ---------- | 
  1    |  steve | 2015-09-12  | 2015-09-09 |  2016-01-10  | 2016-01-21 |
```

is there who can help me to solve this problem? I use CodeIgniter framework.
This my script:

Controllers

```
public function index()
{
    $data['deptlist'] = $this->mcrud->viewkal();
    $data=array('deptlist'  => $this->mcrud->viewkal(),
                'isi'       =>'kalibrasi/v_kalibrasi');
    $this->load->view('layout/wrapper', $data); 

}
```

Models

```
function viewkal()  {
    $this->db->order_by('name','ASC');
    $this->db->group_by('name');
    $query = $this->db->get('mytabel');  
    return $query->result();                             
}
```

Views

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th><?php echo date('Y', strtotime('-2 year')); ?></th>  
        <th><?php echo date('Y', strtotime('-1 year')); ?></th> 
        <th><?php echo date('Y', strtotime('0 year')); ?></th>  
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
        foreach ($deptlist as $row ) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->id_alat; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->nama_alat; ?></td>
        <?php 
            $result = $row->tanggal;
            $data = strtotime($row->tanggal);  
            $tahun = date('Y',$data);

            if ( $tahun == date('Y', strtotime('-3 year'))) {
                echo '<td>'.$result.'</td>';
            } else {
                echo '<td> - </td>';
            }

            if ( $tahun == date('Y', strtotime('-2 year'))) {
                echo '<td>'.$result.'</td>';
            } else {
                echo '<td> - </td>';
            }

            if ( $tahun == date('Y', strtotime('-1 year'))) {
                echo '<td>'.$result.'</td>';
            } else {
                echo '<td> - </td>';
            }           

            if ( $tahun == date('Y', strtotime('0 year'))) {
                echo '<td>'.$result.'</td>';
            } else {
                echo '<td> - </td>';
            }

            if ( $tahun == date('Y', strtotime('-1 year'))) {
                echo '<td>'.$result.'</td>';
            } else {
                echo '<td> - </td>';
            }
        ?>
    <?php } ?>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add status check it code:
model:

```
public function viewkal(){
    $query = $this->db
        ->select('`id`, `name`, GROUP_CONCAT(`date`) as `date_string`, GROUP_CONCAT(`status`) as `status_string`')
        ->group_by('name')
        ->order_by('name','ASC')
        ->get('mytabel');
    return $query->result();
}
```

controller:

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->model('mcrud');
    $data=array('deptlist'  => $this->mcrud->viewkal(),
        'isi'       =>'kalibrasi/v_kalibrasi');
    $this->load->view('layout/wrapper', $data);
}
```

view:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
        <th colspan="2"><?php echo date('Y', strtotime('-2 year')); ?></th>
        <th colspan="2"><?php echo date('Y', strtotime('-1 year')); ?></th>
        <th colspan="2"><?php echo date('Y', strtotime('0 year')); ?></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>scheduled</th>
        <th>actual</th>
        <th>scheduled</th>
        <th>actual</th>
        <th>scheduled</th>
        <th>actual</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    foreach ($deptlist as $row) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
            <?php
            $status_array = explode(',', $row->status_string);
            $date_array = explode(',', $row->date_string);
            for ($year = date('Y', strtotime('-2 year')); $year <= date('Y'); $year++) {
                $scheduledValue = false;
                $actualValue = false;
                foreach ($date_array as $dateKey => $yearRow) {
                    if (strpos($yearRow, (string)$year) === 0) {
                        if ($status_array[$dateKey] == 'scheduled') {
                            $scheduledValue = $yearRow;
                        } elseif ($status_array[$dateKey] == 'actual') {
                            $actualValue = $yearRow;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ($scheduledValue) {
                    echo "<td>{$scheduledValue}</td>";
                } else {
                    echo '<td> - </td>';

                }
                if ($actualValue) {
                    echo "<td>{$actualValue}</td>";
                } else {
                    echo '<td> - </td>';

                }
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: nice good... it work @Lakremon,   but how i get value ex:field `| id | schedule | actual |` value `1 | 2014-10-12 (value status ok) | 2015-09-09 (value status bad) |`

Comment: @Lakremon..ok, but the value status with value bad does not appear. as an example of the schedule field will appear if the status is ok and actual field will appear if the bad status. I tried to add `->where('status','bad')` I tried to add , but still I only status value ok the show

Comment: Please, change your answer, because I can't understand your issue!

Comment: thanks @Lakremon , I've edited my question, perhaps a little understandable, the problem now get the date of the year based on the status?

Comment: So, I'm fix the answer (changes only in view). Hope it help you! =)

Comment: was incredible , my issues have been resolved , thank you for all your help @Lakremon

Answer (score 1):

So, your modal should be:

```
function viewkal()  {
    $query = $this->db
            ->select('`id`, `name`, GROUP_CONCAT(`date`) as `date_string`')
            ->group_by('name')
            ->order_by('name','ASC')
            ->get('mytabel');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Your controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('mcrud');
    $data=array('deptlist'  => $this->mcrud->viewkal(),
            'isi'       =>'kalibrasi/v_kalibrasi');
    $this->load->view('layout/wrapper', $data);
}
```

And your view:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th><?php echo date('Y', strtotime('-2 year')); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo date('Y', strtotime('-1 year')); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo date('Y', strtotime('0 year')); ?></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    foreach ($deptlist as $row) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
            <?php
            for ($year = date('Y', strtotime('-2 year')); $year <= date('Y'); $year++) {
                $yearFind = false;
                foreach (explode(',', $row->date_string) as $yearRow) {
                    if (strpos($yearRow, (string)$year) === 0) {
                        echo '<td>' . $yearRow . '</td>';
                        continue 2;
                    }
                }
                if (!$yearFind) {
                    echo '<td> - </td>';
                }
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks @Lakremon  for the reply , but the results year not find

Comment: can you help me @Lakremon

Comment: Sorry, forgot answer on your comment. So, I fix some issues and test code on Codeigniter 3.0. Please check it.

Comment: I use CodeIgniter 2.2.0. Her script is actually running but coloumn table is not sequential. so I expected date is not in accordance with the year that I wanted.

Comment: It's not clear for me what you want. Can you explain more detail or edit question?

Comment: wowww ... its amazing, once you update your answer by adding `continue 2;` all in accordance with what I expected runs perfectly ... I do not know say anything else other than thank you for your help ...

Comment: Always happy to help! =)

Comment: Can you help me once again on the same question , but I have an update . I added a field ` status` and how to display the date by ` status` .